# How to reproduce this title inside of a box

Tags: formatting, titles, typography, sourcecode, box

I'd like to produce something like this at the beginning of my document: a box with a centered title and details in the angles like the date, the author, etc. What's the code that produces this output?
[image]

Comment: Use a `tabular*` or `tabularx` environment, with three columns and `multirow`.

Answer (score 2):

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{
left text \hfill right text\par
\hfil Title \hfil\par
left text \hfill right text\par
}}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, this is a template. You can modify the box width, the Title font, etcetera.
[image]